# How does "5.5 | 0 === 5" work?

Tags: javascript

How does `5.5 | 0 === 5` work?

Is `| 0` in this context the bitwise `OR` I suspect it to be? If so, why does it cut off everything after the point?

Comment: @Cristy in this case, I'm not sure it's a duplicate, because code that actually looks like that is probably not really trying to simply do a "floor" operation. That's effectively what's happening, of course.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Bitwise operators always coerce operands to 32-bit integers.

The operation is interpreted as

```
5.5 | (0 === 5)
```

which is

```
5.5 | false
```

which is coerced to

```
5.5 | 0
```

Now the `5.5` is converted to a 32-bit integer, so we have

```
5 | 0
```

which is `5`.

The relational operators bind more tightly than the bitwise operators which can be confusing. If you want to compare the result of a bitwise operator (unlike, say, an addition or multiplication), you have to parenthesize explicitly.

Comment: Ha, what a coincidence :) Is "Bitwise operators always coerce operands to 32-bit integers" true in general i.e. for other languages too?

Comment: Good catch, I had assumed OP was talking about `5.5 | 0` yielding `5` as a result and had just phrased it badly.

Comment: @user2820379 Some languages do this, but many do not. More strongly typed languages like C# don't even define the bitwise operators on non-integer types. e.g. `"foo"|"bar"` results in a compiler error.

Answer (score 4):

The `|` performs operator is a bitwise OR operation, implicitly converting each operand to an 32-bit integer. As [*Pointy* notes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21244614/1715579), `5.5 | 0 === 5` is parsed as `5.5 | (0 === 5)`, which evaluates to `5.5 | false`.

According to the [specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.10):

> …
>   5. Let lnum be ToInt32(lval).
>   6. Let rnum be ToInt32(rval).
>   7. Return the result of applying the bitwise operator @ to lnum and rnum. The result is a signed 32 bit integer.

And since `X | 0` → `X` for any integer, it is effectivly just removing any fractional part of the number.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't equal true, it just doesn't equal false.

```
5.5 | 0 === 5
```

returns

```
5
```

Comment: Operator precedence. `(5.5 | 0) === 5` returns true

Comment: That's only because `0 === 5` is false, is coerced to `0`, and then `5.5 | 0` is `5`.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter The expression `5.5 | 0 === 5` returns `5` for me, while `(5.5 | 0) === 5` returns `true`. I think we need to confirm which expression we're/the question is talking about.

Comment: @ajp15243 the `===` operator is higher-precedence than `|`, so the comparison is carried out first.

Comment: @Pointy I understand that. What I'm pointing out is that the OP's question was about the expression without `( )`, while Yuriy seems to be trying to make a point with the expression that includes `( )`, which is obviously a different expression and not necessarily what is being asked about. If there's a point here with the `( )` expression, I'm not seeing it.

Comment: @ajp15243 ah OK, right.  Questions like this make me really wonder who's typing in code like this :)

Comment: @Pointy lol Agreed. After re-reading, I think I may now see the point Yuriy was trying to make, and I think my confusion, plus other comments around this question, are because people are interpreting what was typed in the question in subtly different ways.

Comment: "It doesn't equal true". Well, `5` **is** truthy. ;-)

Comment: @robg Truthy !== true, as 5 !== true, but because 5 !== false, it results on true